# Rspec tests don't trigger logger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have created some tests in Rspec for one of my models. I found a bug this way, and added some `logger.debug` lines in my model to check variable / method values. However, When I run the Rspec tests again, my log file stays empty, despite the extra `logger.debug` lines. I empty my log and run the tests again and the log file is still empty.

Is there a way to get Rspec to trigger these logging lines? It would be far quicker to debug my model this way.

Comment: it might be a long shot but do a `Rails.logger.debug`.. BTW where are you checking the logs, I mean which file? It might also be possible that the tests are not actually running!

Comment: The tests are running for sure because they are failing. I am using the logger in my ActiveRecord model so Rails.logger is not actually necessary. It just seems like Rspec doesn't trigger any logging in models by default.

Comment: what was the file you were looking at, for the logs?

Comment: you should be looking at `logs/test.log`.. AFAIK RSpec logs are stored in that file.

Comment: My mannnnn, thanks!!!